# List all EC2 EBS snapshots taken on a particular date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I am trying to list all EBS volume snapshot which is taken on a particular date so that i can automate a copy via bash script across region for better disaster recovery
I have an another bash script that creates snapshots of all in use EBS volumes and delete all which is older then 30 days. I need to copy all which is taken on a previous date across an another region.

I tried many jmespath switches (which is not giving any output) some of them are as:-

```
$aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Sanpshots[?StartTime >= `2018-06-25`]|[?StartTime <= `2018-06-27`]'
$aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Sanpshots[?StartTime == `2018-06-25`]
```

I looked many pages but not able to find for a particular date listing.
Please suggest some switches,sorting methods,links or anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured the JMESpath switch from doc right [here.](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#paren-expressions) 
So in order to search for a particular date i applied a switch which search between two dates. for example:-

```
'Snapshots[?(StartTime >= `2018-06-27`) && (StartTime <= `2018-06-28`)]
```

Reason why "==" is not working in the switch as it used for exact match string.

So the complete string is :-

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --query 'Snapshots[?(StartTime >= `2018-06-27`) && (StartTime <= `2018-06-28`)].{ID:SnapshotId,ST:StartTime}' --output text --region $regionname
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you'll need some programmatic way of calculating "30 days ago", you're better-off doing this in a programming language, such as:

```
import boto3
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Get my AWS Account ID
myAccount = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account']

# Connect to EC2
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

# Get a list of snapshots for my AWS account (not all public ones)
snapshots = client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=[myAccount])['Snapshots']

# Find snapshots more than 30 days old
oldest_date = datetime.now(pytz.utc) - timedelta(days=30)
old_snapshots = [s for s in snapshots if s['StartTime'] < oldest_date]

# Delete the old snapshots
for s in old_snapshots:
  client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId = s['SnapshotId'])
```

Comment: Thanks John as always. But i don't need listing taken 30 days ago for deletion , i need snapshot listing which is created on a particular date (2 days back of current date) so that i can copy them to another region. That is why i am looking jmespath switches or any way for sorting.